# Disable anonymous connection to jhipster 4.x Angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster. I've successfully generated my firts jhipster project (Jhipster version 4.3.0 (HTTP session Authentication, Angular 4 [Beta], etc).

How could i disable anonymous login so that everybody authenticate via a login page (and not login modal) to the application ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change functionality of angular component login.

Comment: Could you please help me by giving more details?